# Take and save screenshot of UICollectionViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, screenshot, uicollectionviewcell, watchkit

How can I take a screenshot of all my cells in my `UICollectionView` and save them to disk (Every cell in its own file)? The `UICollectionViewCells` are very complex and I want to show them in my Watch App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would HIGHLY recommend not doing this for your Apple Watch UI.  If you do want to do it you can call `- (BOOL)drawViewHierarchyInRect:(CGRect)rect afterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates` on each `UICollectionViewCell`.  The code would look something like (this is untested code so it may have some typos, but you should get the gist of what to do).

```
for (int section = 0; section < collectionView.numberOfSections; section++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < [collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section]; row++)
    {
        NSIndexPath* path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
        UICollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:path];
        //You may need to change the size here
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.bounds.size);
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [cell drawViewHierarchyInRect:cell.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
        UIImage* img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        //img has the image for the cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a big image in my cell and some smaller images above (e.g. a favorite star and some other small icons). It's not possible to put an image view above an image view in watch kit, so I have to combine the images before. Is it better to do that with core graphics in code?

Comment: If you need to create custom composed graphics I would recommend doing it with core graphics.  (Though I suppose if you sized your collection cells to the right size your idea above could work.).  Also, you can set a background image on a WKInterfaceGroup and then have another WKInterfaceImage over the top of it.